# How can I remove missing values on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, null

I have a data set that uses the number -9999.000 to represent missing values. I need to remove these missing values in order to make some calculations, but I am unsure how to go about this.

Comment: what type of data is 'the dataset'?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no parallel of arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management so the usual course is to translate the data again https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/redefining-nodata-value-into-zero-in-qgis however if you don't mind a little bit of python https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319249/inserting-nodata-value-using-gdal will define the existing -9999 values as nodata in the existing raster. If your image happens to be a text format like ASCII or header format like BIL/BSQ the nodata value can be edited in a **good** text editor like notepad++.